# Pass commands to a running external CMD

Tags: c#, cmd, external

Here is my problem, i have a currently running program that runs in the background and is only accessible via a cmd window in which you pass commands to control said program. What im trying to do is send a command from my c# winform to the cmd which then executes the command. Im basicly trying to code a gui for this program.

Cheers.

Comment: What exactly does "can be controlled via a cmd window" mean? How can it be controlled specifically? Whether it's possible or not would be highly dependent on that information.

Comment: I can issue program specific commands in the cmd. Lets say help would yield me a list of all commands that can be entered into the cmd window.

Comment: Is the "program which is not yours" currently running?  Or are you trying to invoke it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide that information in the question itself so it can be seen, instead of burying it in the comments. As I said before, the answer to this question is *highly dependent* on this information, so make it available and easily seen.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's a little more involved, but this can be done by using the Windows Api.
Which means, you need to import some native libraries via P/Invoke.

First you need to get a handle to the console window. You can do this via [FindWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633499%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([P/Invoke signature](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.FindWindow)).

Next to send some key-strokes there's multiple options. The most pretty one I guess is to use [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([P/Invoke signature](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/SendMessage.html)) with the [WM_KEYDOWN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ms646280%28v=vs.71%29) and [WM_KEYUP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/ms646281%28v=vs.71%29) messages and the [VK_](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/dd375731%28v=vs.71%29) key as lParam argument.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is running --  You aren't going to be able to send commands to a running app unless it's designed to accept them somehow..   It either needs to have an open port or some way to 'send the command' to the running app.

Most apps that "you can't modify" can only be called with specific parameters at startup, unless they were designed to take input at runtime.

Comment: Well im able to input commands into the cmd manually and then execute them like normal with enter, is there no way to emulate me tipping a string into the cmd window ?

Comment: By [tipping](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/tipping) you mean "sending keystrokes"?

Comment: Well that is a different story, yes.  You can use the Process object to inject command s to the standard input stream while a process is running.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21291927/how-to-send-a-command-to-an-executable/21292269#21292269